# D3.js chart brush and Crossfilter.js scales out of sync

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale, crossfilter, brush

I am trying to highlight selections in my D3 bar chart using the brush extent.

[JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Nyquist212/yys2mqkx/](http://jsfiddle.net/Nyquist212/yys2mqkx/)

I'm using crossfilter to `reduceCount()` my data so I can plot score distribution. But this seems to be screwing with my x-scale. The effect is most noticeable when you drag the entire brush extent.

Online example with full dataset is [here](http://colinwhite.net/d3brush/) (takes a few secs to load).

I'm using linear scales but it appears as if the brush coordinates are out of sync with the bar chart coordinate space (see console logging).

[image]

My brush extent does not appear to be correctly binding to the `rects` in front of it.

My problem appears to lie around line# 840 where I'm trying to do something like this,

```
var extent = brush.extent(), 
    lower = extent[0], 
    upper = extent[1];

d3.selectAll("rect")
  .style("opacity", function(d) {
       return d.key >= lower && d.key <= upper || brush.empty() ? "1" : ".4";
       })

 }
```

I'm trying to achieve [this effect](http://codepen.io/dennyglee/pen/pfahG) which highlights the selected bars and fades the unselected.

Can someone pls help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brush expects to use the x scale you passed in to invert the mouse coordinates to produce the target value in the domain ([source](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/svg/brush.js#L360)).  Unfortunately, you're not actually using that x scale to draw the bars, so it looks like the brush is off.  In fact, it's your bars that are off, which can be seen by updating line 806 to actually use the x scale that the brush is using. ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psyvpv7e/))

```
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        return x(d.key);
    })
```

Well, that's great, except it's clearly not at all what you're looking for.

[image: overlapping bars]

Now you just need to figure out how to produce an x scale that will do what you want for both the bars and the brush.  The [Linear Scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear-scales) API documentation will be of great help there.

**EDIT:** This should get you started.  Update the scale to use an ordinal one with the keys as the domain.

```
var keys = byScrGrp.all()
    .map(function (d) { return d.key; });

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(keys)
    .rangeBands([0, width]);
```

Update the bar rendering to use the new ordinal scale.

```
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(d.key);
    })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
```

Update the brushmove method to brute-force which groups are selected.

```
    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .style("opacity", function(d) {
            var k = x(d.key) + 0.5 * x.rangeBand();
            return  s[0] <= k && k <= s[1] ? "1" : ".2"; 
        });
```

Also update the brush initializer to use the new coordinates.

```
    .extent([x(1.1),x(0.9)])
```

For me Chrome does alright with this but Firefox kind of chokes, at least inside JSFiddle.  There are clearly opportunities for optimization here.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Laxtj26r/2/)

Comment: Interesting... I had naively assumed my problem was the brush rather than the bars. The x-axis is "ideally" a threshold scale. 0-2 in increments of tenths (one decimal place) with the scores in two decimal places. I understand `brush()` does not have an `invert()` for non-linear scales? I could find only two examples of ordinal brushing and was unable to translate them to my model. Do you recommend I persist with  [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4349509) and [this](http://bl.ocks.org/chrisbrich/4173587) example?

Comment: Thanks ;)... Yep, I think those examples are exactly what you're looking for.  In particular, as long as you don't have more than a handful of bars, it's reasonable to do a brute-force search for matching elements as in Mike Bostock's example: `symbol.classed("selected", function(d) { return s[0] <= (d = x(d)) && d <= s[1]; });`

Comment: Monsieur Couchand, merci beacoup. [C'est ca!](http://jsfiddle.net/Nyquist212/8vL2w8uw/22/)